# PHP Startup ffmpeg Unable to initialize module

Tags: php, dll, ffmpeg

When start Apache I get this error..

How can I solve it?

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: ffmpeg: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
```

- extension=php_ffmpeg.dll : added to php.ini
- php_ffmpeg.dll copied to php/ext
- avcodex-51.dll/ avformat-51.dll/ avutil-49.dll/ pthreadGC2.dll : added to C:\Windows\SysWOW64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php_ffmpeg.dll was compiled with an older version of PHP. It's possible your PHP installation was updated but the module was not.  You will need to get an updated version the the php_ffmpeg module or remove it.

Comment: where do I find php_ffmpeg.dll